# How do i come up with a generic way to store all reference data in my database in SQL?

Tags: sql, database-design

In my database, a customer can have many accounts and an account can be secured by many securities. A customer can be associated to another customer in the bank. For example property developer may be associated with a Surveyor.

A customer cannot be associated to another customer twice.

I have set up tables for Customers, Accounts Securities and Associations in SQL.

In terms of reference data the business has the following requirement: Accounts, Securities and Associations can be of several types For example, an account can be savings, credit; a security can be a bond, house, and an association can be that Customer 1 is the surveyor of Customer 2 (surveyor being the association).  They do not want many tables to store each of these types. They want a generic way to store all reference (types) data in the database.

I am very new to this and I cannot figure out a generic way to store the reference data. Do i need another table of types which would have Type ID Pk and then the description ( if i do it this way the table would be mixed with unrelated data)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I don't understand what you are trying to do here at all. Can you post some details about your tables and the data you are trying to store? Also, be careful with tagging as mysql and sql server are NOT the same thing.

Comment: Since your question is about database design, it may be more applicable for the Database Administrators Stack Exchange website than SO. Hover over the upper right icon to see the other Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: Hi. Please give clear requirements and some design(s) for it. Try *some* design that records the appropriate info. Tell us what textbook/reference you are following. Otherwise you are just asking for us rewrite such a textbook/reference and to design for you.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand, you will have to come with a design that will require to be in the 4NF in order to be reliable and upgradeable.  You are going to need a bunch of tables to support the information if you want this to be done correctly and avoid any update issues that can turn the information stored in the DB inconsistent.

Let's start with the basic tables:

```
user_table                    
ID (PK, NN)                   
First Name                    
Last Name
Any other Field

account_type_table                    
ID (PK, NN)                    
Account Type (savings, checking, etc)

account_security_type_table                    
ID (PK, NN)                    
type of security (bond, house, etc)

users_account_table
ID (PK, NN)
UserID (Foreign Key from users table)
AccountTypeID (Foreign Key from account_type table)
AccountSecurityID (Foreign key from account_security_type table)
Any other information for the account
```

The previous approach is for just 1 type of security for account, if you need to have multiple securities for a single account we need to modify the user_account_table and create another table that will link the account to the security type like this.

```
users_account_table
ID (PK, NN)
UserID (Foreign Key from users table)
AccountTypeID (Foreign Key from account_type table)
Any other information for the account

account_security_table
ID (PK, NN)
AccountID (Foreign key from users_account_table)
SecurityID (Foreign key from account_security_type_table)
Any other field you need.
```

For the surveyor part I don't really understand what it is about, if you explain this even further probably I will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide you need a look up table for types, then yes you can create a generic table of Types, and add a column that describes what the type is particular to.

- TypeID - an IDENTITY Column
- TypeDescription - (eg: Savings, Credit,
  Bond, House, etc)
- TypeOf (or whatever name you prefer) - (eg:    Account, Security,
  Association)